# Problema de conexion en MySQL y VisualStudio para un Login [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException]

Tags: c#, mysql

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''12345'' at line 1'

Tengo un problema, al momnto de colocar el usuario y contraseña, ocurre el error. Este es el codigo.

```
            MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=thepacioli; Uid=root; pwd=Valentin_01; SslMode=none");
            conectar.Open();

            MySqlCommand codigo = new MySqlCommand();
            MySqlConnection conectanos = new MySqlConnection();
            codigo.Connection = conectar;

            codigo.CommandText = ("select *from usuario where nombre='" + txtusuario.Text + "'and clave'" + txtcontraseña.Text + "'");

            MySqlDataReader leer = codigo.ExecuteReader();

            conectar.Close();
```

Comment: te falta el = despues de la palabra 'clave'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

te falta el = despues de la palabra 'clave'

Comment: Las preguntas que son solamente errores tipograficos no deben contestarse

Comment: Revisar [ask] y [answer].

Answer (score 0):

El query esta mal, te falta el '=' al comparar la contraseña.

```
    codigo.CommandText = ("select *from usuario where nombre='" + txtusuario.Text + "'and clave='" + txtcontraseña.Text + "'");
```

A parte de eso hay muchas otras cosas mal, partiendo del hecho de que el código esta tremendamente inseguro.

Trata de usar parameter binding como se muestra en este ejemplo

```
   static void CountCourses(String connectionString, Int32 year) {  
      String commandText = "Select Count([CourseID]) FROM [MySchool].[dbo].[Course] Where Year=@Year";  
      SqlParameter parameterYear = new SqlParameter("@Year", SqlDbType.Int);  
      parameterYear.Value = year;  

      Object oValue = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connectionString, commandText, CommandType.Text, parameterYear);  
      Int32 count;  
      if (Int32.TryParse(oValue.ToString(), out count))  
         Console.WriteLine("There {0} {1} course{2} in {3}.", count > 1 ? "are" : "is", count, count > 1 ? "s" : null, year);  
   }
```

Y aún mucho más importante aléjate de eso y trata de usar mejor entity framework y LinQ

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html#connector-net-ef6-codefirst

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-databinding-linq-entities.html

Comment: Suponer que el codigo es inseguro solamente porque concatena variables no es algo que sirva. si es una app de escritorio para que use el, el codigo alcanza y sobra. Tu ejemplo deberia estar en español y explicado. y recomendar EF sin un porque tampoco esta bueno. te estaba por dar un voto positivo, pero por todo eso lo deje neutro.

Comment: Es código inseguro no es una suposición, como si lo es suponer que es una aplicación de escritorio, por no mencionar que las aplicaciones de escritorio tambien son una superficie vulnerable, el atacante del sistema perfectamente puede ser el usuario final inyectando SQL para modificar cosas que se supone no puede hacer desde la aplicación.

Comment: Y quien puso lo de los ejemplos en español? eso es un despropósito, no podemos reinventarnos toda la web para dar una respuesta. Eso puede tener un propósito legítimo , pero no es para nada práctico. Salvo que uno tenga todo el día para querer ayudar y escribir artículos por cada pregunta...

Comment: De igual forma, como es eso de no recomendar algo sin una justificación? debo escribir otro artículo explicándolo?  No necesito los puntos, solo vengo a ayudar, pero si esas son las políticas que están implementando no creo que muchos mas se animen a ayudar. Están poniendo demasiada fricción y burocracia en la comunidad.

Comment: Mi idea no era discutir. Se entendio mal mi comentario. O lo explique mal. La respuesta no es mala. Aunque no deberia responderse si solo es un error  de sintaxis. Solo te marcaba algunos puntos que podrian mejorarse.

Comment: Chicos, chicos. No se peleen. Gracias por su ayuda, todavia voy en la universidad. No es para el banco